# Graph bootstrapped joint CI of two statistics in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, data-visualization, bootstrap

I have estimated a mixed-effects logistic regression with glmer
and want to draw a bootstrapped confidence-region for the mean predicted probability for two subgroups of the sample.

I have a $1000 \times 2$ Matrix $X$ containing the bootstrapped mean predicted probabilities for the two groups.
One could now compute the empirical covariance matrix $S$ and draw a
circle around the means using the metric induced by $S^{-1}$,
i.e. drawing a confidence ellipsoid based on normality-assumption.

Are there any widely used alternatives to this approach that do not imply distributional assumptions?

skeletor